# Can't correctly import external JS into Aurelia application (dataTables)

Tags: javascript, datatables, aurelia

I'm trying to get this example to work within my Aurelia application.

https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

I am mainly interested in the blue + orb.

In my aurelia application I added

```
"datatables-responsive": "npm:datatables-responsive@^1.0.7",
```

to my package.json.

I also added:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/responsive.bootstrap.min.css">
```

to my index.html.

I added `import datatables-responsive;` to my VM but I get errors saying it can't find different resources.

```
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9000/dist/datatables.net.js
    Error loading http://localhost:9000/dist/datatables.net.js as "datatables.net" from http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/datatables-responsive@1.0.7/js/dataTables.responsive.js
Stack trace:
o@http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/system.js:4:12694
e/</I/s.onreadystatechange@http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/system.js:4:13219
```

I don't understand why it is looking for datatables.net.js when it should already have datatables imported. Any suggestions on resolving this?

Config.js

```
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "babel",
  babelOptions: {
    "optional": [
      "runtime",
      "optimisation.modules.system"
    ]
  },
  paths: {
    "*": "dist/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },
  map: {
    "aurelia-animator-css": "npm:aurelia-animator-css@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
    "aurelia-bootstrapper": "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
    "aurelia-fetch-client": "npm:aurelia-fetch-client@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
    "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
    "aurelia-history-browser": "npm:aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
    "aurelia-loader-default": "npm:aurelia-loader-default@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
    "aurelia-logging-console": "npm:aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
    "aurelia-pal-browser": "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
    "aurelia-polyfills": "npm:aurelia-polyfills@1.0.0-beta.1.1.2",
    "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
    "aurelia-templating-binding": "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
    "aurelia-templating-resources": "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
    "aurelia-templating-router": "npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
    "babel": "npm:babel-core@5.8.38",
    "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.38",
    "bootstrap": "github:twbs/bootstrap@3.3.6",
    "core-js": "npm:core-js@1.2.6",
    "datatables": "npm:datatables@1.10.11",
    "datatables-responsive": "npm:datatables-responsive@1.0.7",
    "fetch": "github:github/fetch@0.11.0",
    "font-awesome": "npm:font-awesome@4.6.1",
    "text": "github:systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.3",
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0": {
      "assert": "npm:assert@1.3.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0": {
      "path-browserify": "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2": {
      "process": "npm:process@0.11.2"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0": {
      "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
    },
    "github:twbs/bootstrap@3.3.6": {
      "jquery": "npm:jquery@2.2.3"
    },
    "npm:assert@1.3.0": {
      "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-animator-css@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0": {
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.3.2": {
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0": {
      "aurelia-event-aggregator": "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-history": "npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-history-browser": "npm:aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-loader-default": "npm:aurelia-loader-default@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-logging-console": "npm:aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-pal-browser": "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-polyfills": "npm:aurelia-polyfills@1.0.0-beta.1.1.2",
      "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-templating-binding": "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-templating-resources": "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-templating-router": "npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0": {
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0": {
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-framework@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.3.2",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0": {
      "aurelia-history": "npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-loader-default@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1": {
      "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0": {
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0": {
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-polyfills@1.0.0-beta.1.1.2": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-route-recognizer@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0": {
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1": {
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-event-aggregator": "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-history": "npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-route-recognizer": "npm:aurelia-route-recognizer@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0": {
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.3.2",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.3.2",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0": {
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2"
    },
    "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.2": {
      "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.0-beta.1.3.2",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0"
    },
    "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.38": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:core-js@1.2.6": {
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.1"
    },
    "npm:datatables-responsive@1.0.7": {
      "datatables": "npm:datatables@1.10.11",
      "jquery": "npm:jquery@2.2.3",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:datatables@1.10.11": {
      "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.21",
      "jquery": "npm:jquery@2.2.3"
    },
    "npm:font-awesome@4.6.1": {
      "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.21"
    },
    "npm:inherits@2.0.1": {
      "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:process@0.11.2": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:util@0.10.3": {
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: show your config.js

Comment: @FabioLuz I added it to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue. It was all in how I was adding the libraries to my project, how I was importing them, and a slight issue with the way JSPM loads the library (at least I think someone with more experience with Javascript can correct me).

The solution is at this link.

https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/issues/473

A working example:

Add the following libraries to your project

```
jspm install datatables.net=npm:datatables.net
jspm install datatables.net-responsive=npm:datatables.net-responsive
jspm install datatables.net-responsive-bs=npm:datatables.net-responsive-bs
jspm install datatables.net-bs=npm:datatables.net-bs
```

Index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aurelia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jspm_packages/npm/font-awesome@4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body aurelia-app="main">
    <div class="splash">
      <div class="message">Aurelia Navigation Skeleton</div>
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </div>

    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
      // ensure jQuery is loaded and set before other imports in you project
      System.import('jquery')
        .then(jquery => {
          window.jQuery = jquery;
          window.$ = jquery;

          // now load and bootstrap aurelia
          return System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

welcome.html:

```
<template>
  <section class="au-animate">
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px">
      <div>test datatables</div>
      <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%"></table>
    </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

welcome.js

```
import * as datatable from 'datatables';
//following only once in you app i think
import * as responsive from 'datatables.net-responsive';
import * as responsiveBs from 'datatables.net-responsive-bs';
import * as netBs from 'datatables.net-bs';

let responsive = responsive.default(); // to change settings?
responsiveBs.default();
netBs.default();

export class Welcome {
  dataSet = [
      ['Ken','Husband','Home'],
      ['Barbie','Wife','Home']
    ];

  attached() {
   // can call: responsive(settings, options);
    $('#example').DataTable({
       select: true,
       data: this.dataSet,
       columns: [
         { title: "Name" },
         { title: "Position" },
         { title: "Office" }
        ]
   });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding it in the export.Js file?